# Android change Tab from Fragment when onclick is called

Tags: android, button, tabs, fragment

I have a project that has 4 tabs using the actionbar, each of which have their own fragment that they display when the tab is clicked.

What I would like to do is reset the current tab to another (for example from tab4 to tab2) when a button is clicked in the current tab. I'm not sure how to go about this since Fragments are sort of alien to me. How would I be able to get the currently selected tab? How would I be able to set the new tab?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean myTab.setCurrentTab(i) and myTab.getCurrentTab(). You can declare a

```
myTab.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    //do something
}});
```

for your event handling.

Comment: where does myTab come from?  How does one overide such activitys from FragmentActivity